# EF Core 6: How to implement controller that returns joined data?

Tags: entity-framework-core, controller

I have a database with several different, but related tables:

```
class AccountInfo {
    string id;
    string name;
    string email;
}

class ExtraInfo {
    string id;
    string proxy;
}

class UserInfo {
    AccountInfo account;
    ExtraInfo extra;
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<AccountInfo> AccountInfo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExtraInfo> ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ExtraInfoController : ODataController
{
    private readonly DS2DbContext _context;

    private readonly ILogger<UserInfoController> _logger;

    public ExtraInfoController(DS2DbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 15)]
    public IQueryable<UserInfo> Get() {
        IQueryable<UserInfo> query =
            from a in _context.AccountInfo
            from x in _context.ExtraInfo
            where (a.id == x.id)
            select new UserInfo() { account = a, extra = x };
        return query;
    }
```

The query in ExtraInfoController.Get() works, but the result cannot be transferred back to the calling code, because the DbSet is declared for type ExtraInfo and I guess because of the way Blazor mangles all the pseudo code passed to it into working code, so it expects the return type to be IQueryable and not IQeryable.

I am new to EF core, so I don't know how to create a controller that is not directly related to a db table that would do the desired join and return an IQueryable without there being a UserInfo table in the db.

Comment: Read up on navigation properties for relationships between entities. There is very rarely a need to explicitly use Joins in EF Linq. The whole premise of an ORM is to avoid writing SQL, not just provide an alternative syntax.

Comment: Sorry, but this comment is totally useless for me.

Comment: Associate the entities as a one-to-one between AccountInfo and ExtraInfo. Put a navigation property between them and update the query to load AccountInfo including a.ExtraInfo. What you are trying to do is essentially return a DTO (UserInfo) containing two entity references as an `IQueryable`. If `IQueryable` & EF is supported for that Blazor control then your best bet is passing a pure EF entity graph. I suspect this would only work /w Blazor server-side. Beyond that you could consider server-side pagination returning an `IEnumerable` for a page if that is why it would take `IQueryable`.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.